# Malewarebytes Business for Personal Use Question

Tags: malware

I currently use the MalewareBytes personal free version. I have the opportunity to use "MalewareBytes for Business" through my university. Is there any benefit to using "MalrewareBytes for Business" for my personal computer? Does that even make sense (since I am not a business, just an individual)?

Comment: We cannot comment on the usefulness of one product version over another. Read the vendor's feature list to see if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot address comparison of specific products on this StackExchange.

However, I do have a bit of experience with the product you mention, and it comes with a warning.

From experience:

Malwarebytes works as advertised but is is famous for urging you to use BoostSpeed.  It tries to install it by default.  It is a bit nagging.

As for your question, there is likely no difference other than that the university is paying them for non-personal use.

I would bet that it is the same program either way.

Here's the warning:

Be aware that BoostSpeed also installs Geek Buddy, which opens up your PC to remote-control from outside.

I have tested BoostSpeed enough to know that it hasn't made any visible difference in the speed of my computers.

-->  If you get BoostSpeed installed, try it, then change your mind, be sure to uninstall both BoostSpeed and Geek Buddy or you will still be open for remote control from the outside.